# How to find height of binary tree if i have total number of nodes

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I know total number of nodes in the tree. using this how to find height of the tree?

Comment: You have to assume it is balanced, or it can't be done (unless you want some useless bounds).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a balanced tree, then the height (number of levels) is ceiling(lg (n+1)) where ceiling always rounds up to the next highest integer, and lg is base-2 logarithm.  If you have certain types of self-balancing trees (which are not always completely balanced, but highly balanced) then it is also possible to give informative bounds on the height of the tree.  If you just assume an arbitrary binary tree (say, where every internal node has two children) then the height could be as much as (n-1)/2, for example if you have a tree that looks like a comb.

Comment: @jwpat7: log2(3+1)=2, so ceil(log2(3+1))=2. log2(4+1)=2.32... so ceil(log2(4+1))=3. That seems to correlate with your height values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a queue.
Push root into the queue.
height = 0
Loop
    nodeCount = size of queue

        // If number of nodes at this level is 0, return height
    if nodeCount is 0
        return Height;
    else
        increase Height

        // Remove nodes of this level and add nodes of 
        // next level
    while (nodeCount > 0)
        pop node from front
        push its children to queue
        decrease nodeCount
       // At this point, queue has nodes of next level
```

For more information: [Click this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-method-to-find-height-of-binary-tree/)